# Object not found: chefzero - but no chefzero configured

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

During `vagrant up --provision` it stops with an error:

```
...
==> default: [2016-05-23T08:05:57+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.11.1 ***
==> default: [2016-05-23T08:05:57+00:00] INFO: Platform: x86_64-linux
==> default: [2016-05-23T08:05:57+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 1725
==> default: [2016-05-23T08:06:04+00:00] INFO: GET /organizations/chef/nodes/vagrant-0393a049
==> default: [2016-05-23T08:06:04+00:00] INFO: #<ChefZero::RestErrorResponse: 404: Object not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes/vagrant-0393a049>
....
==> default: [2016-05-23T08:06:04+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Object not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes/vagrant-0393a049
==> default: [2016-05-23T08:06:04+00:00] INFO: POST /organizations/chef/nodes
==> default: --- POST BODY ---
==> default: {"name":"vagrant-0393a049","chef_environment":"_default","json_class":"Chef::Node","automatic":{},"normal":{},"chef_type":"node","default":{},"override":{},"run_list":[]}
==> default: --- END POST BODY ---
...
```

Problem is - I haven't `chefzero` at all:

```
$ grep -r "chefzero" . | wc -l
0
```

Maybe - it's somewhere in dependencies, but I can't find where.

Also - this `Vagrantfile` was used before and no changes in `Vagrantfile`:

```
  config.berkshelf.enabled = true
  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.add_recipe "apt"
    chef.add_recipe "nginx::repo"
    chef.add_recipe "nginx"
    chef.add_recipe "php5-fpm::install"
    chef.add_recipe "future::mysql"
    chef.add_recipe "future::nginx"
    chef.add_recipe "future::php"
    chef.add_recipe "future"
    chef.add_recipe "future::vm"
    chef.add_recipe "python"
    chef.add_recipe "future::boto3"
    ...
```

Also - I see a bunch of files like `vagrant20160523-25017-1fg91dt2.lock` in directory with `Vagrantfile`, and directories like `d20160523-21769-1yiatxb`. They appears each time after VM booted up.

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Vagrant temporary files in directory was because of wrong `/tmp` permissions.

Answer (score 0):

There has been few issues reported for a few days from the most recent chef version

the solution is to downgrade your chef version. In your Vagrantfile just mention the chef version to use, for example

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.version = "12.10.24"
    chef.add_recipe ....
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, just - when I'm trying to change version - each time I have `"Omnitruck artifact does not exist for version 12.9.38 on platform ubuntu"`. Same for 14.04, 12.04, 15,16 and Chef versions 12.10.24, 12.9.41, 12.9.38 :-|

Comment: @setevoy Can you try to delete /opt/chef-client from your VirtualMachine and run provisioner again?

Comment: @glg Hi, thanks for the comment. Unfortunately - no, can't, as this Q was asked ~year ago :-)

Comment: @setevoy oops I miss that :)